# UnableToAdaptException for new web app in Websphere Liberty + Vaadin + IntelliJ

Tags: java, websphere, vaadin

**Update**: to test out the Vaadin 7 tutorials I had to check out another application server (tomcat 8) to get it up and running. As per user Gas tips I tried changing to web app 3.0 which seemed to break references for Vaadin 7.

**Update 2**: When using IDEA to generate the code base, the option to select version for Web Applicatin only contains version 3.1 for my installation. I still to new to IDEA and what settings to tinker with to get this fixed for 3.0 and below, but using Gas' response when the new schemaLocation fixes the issue.

---

I've just installed:

- IntelliJ Ultimate Ed IDEA
- JDK8 Websphere
- Liberty Profile (wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.3)
- Vaadin 7 full zip framework

I'm following the tutorial from the Vaadin book to set up a default project and then create project guide goes through fine. However, when I try to start up the server I get this error message both in Run and in Debug mode.

```
Connected to server
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0,026 seconds.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: Could not start web application VaadinDemo_war_exploded.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application VaadinDemo_war_exploded. The exception message was: com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException: com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.DDParser$ParseException: CWWKC2262E: The version 3.1 does not match the namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee in the /WEB-INF/web.xml deployment descriptor.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server liberty-oscar is ready to run a smarter planet.
```

And this is what web.xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>com.MyVaadinApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Am I missing something since these are all fresh installs or should I configure something else? All settings are "default" for my listed installs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.3 doesn't support Servlet 3.1 yet. Try to change your deployment descriptor to:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
```

**UPDATE**

This `servlet` tag works perfectly in Liberty. So there is something wrong with your setup.

```
<servlet>
    <description>
        This is the description for the sample servlet
    </description>
    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: So I tried that and it seems the <servlet> tags aren't supported in 3.0 and below. I had to download tomcat (8) and everything works fine. I'm doing this to learn how to use Vaadin so I guess it's ok. But my goul here is to specifically use Liberty so I guess I'll have to go look at Vaadin (6) if I wan't to get some progress there.

Thanks for your input anyway!

Comment: @oalmgren `<servlet> tags aren't supported in 3.0 and below` - where did you find that information, it **is totally wrong**, they are supported since very long time.

Comment: @oalmgren Looking at this page: https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.3/7.3.2/release-notes.html vaadin7 requires servlet 2.4, and is supported in WAS 8. But I'd suggest to switch to Java v7 instead of if you are running 8 (dont know what JDK8 WebSphere means)

Comment: Typo: JDK8 Websphere -> Using JDK8, <br> Websphere Liberty Profile

Ok, I'll try JDK7 and see how it goes. Also, the <servlet> stuff seems to be a mismatch reading of sources. Unfounded statement.